# Current draw for +/2/3/0 models

Tags: pi-2, power, power-supply, pi-zero

Essentially ["What's the current draw and supply voltage tolerance?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/341/whats-the-current-draw-and-supply-voltage-tolerance) but for newer models.

Comment: I don't know who's been down-voting (-2 when I looked), but they're wrong. This is a sensible question. Also, if someone has an issue with it, they're supposed to comment.

Comment: I've edited this to be more general since the answers are.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to click links, the Raspberry Pi can handle `4.75v` to `5.25v`.

As for the current draw/power consumption, here are some numbers:

```
All of these are bare-bone (does not have any peripherals/accessories attached)

*** Fun Fact (Tested on Pi1 B+) ***
Any turned-off Raspberry Pi that's still plugged in: 75 mA

*** Idle ***
Raspberry Pi 2 B:    420mA
Raspberry Pi B+:     230-240mA
Raspberry Pi B:      320-330mA
Raspberry Pi A+:     180-240mA
Raspberry Pi A:      120-140mA
Raspberry Pi Zero:   60-70mA
Raspberry Pi Zero W: 100ma
Raspberry Pi 3 B:    280-320mA

*** Under Load/Max ***
Raspberry Pi 2 B:    450-650mA
Rasbperry Pi B+:     300-600mA
Raspberry Pi B:      380-450mA
Raspberry Pi A+:     200-300mA
Raspberry Pi A:      170-300mA
Raspberry Pi Zero:   120-150mA
Raspberry Pi Zero W: 160-230mA
Raspberry Pi 3 B:    500-800mA
```

Take note that some of them have a bit of give-or-take.

Also take note that you will rarely reach these numbers in the real world. These measurements are based on stress tests that maxes out the unit.

Source: [1](http://raspi.tv/2014/raspberry-pi-a-how-much-power-does-it-need) [2](https://learn.adafruit.com/embedded-linux-board-comparison/power-usage) [3](https://github.com/geerlingguy/raspberry-pi-dramble/wiki/Power-Consumption) [4](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6050) [5](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-power) [6](http://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi2-power-and-performance-measurement) [7](http://raspi.tv/2017/how-much-power-does-pi-zero-w-use)

Comment: Ok, +1 for being more comprehensive than my answer :-D But do the sources that I have linked not report a lower consumption for the A+?

Comment: @Ghanima corrected

Comment: The official docs https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs state a figure of 0.82A for the Pi 2 under stress. 1.2A looks to be too much, considering there's a 1.1A polyfuse at the input.

Comment: @M.Hassaan Someone finally found the typo that I placed intentionally.

Comment: Your "Fun Fact" is wrong - "turned off" pi (i.e. halt) use approx same as idle (60mA or more)

Comment: @MikeRedrobe There's a difference between turned/powered off (command: `sudo poweroff` or `sudo shutdown now`) and halt `sudo halt`. I specifically mentioned "turned-off". Here's the test results from a few minutes ago: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=932091#p932091

Comment: You're using an inaccurate usb meter (at <100mA) - try a multimeter. Pi never goes below 60mA even with no SD inserted. Idle figures are correct though.

Comment: @MikeRedrobe It seems you're right. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=932861#p932861

Comment: Do you know if this same info for the Pi 3 is available yet? (It's not on the Raspberry Pi page linked in the answer below)

Comment: @allanonmage http://blog.pimoroni.com/raspberry-pi-3/

Comment: Sooner or later, I'm going to re-do all of these using more accurate tools.

Answer (score 3):

For current draw I doubt you'll find anything more official than http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs

On the voltage side the only official comment made will be use the USB specs of 4.75V to 5.25V.

However if you look on the official site at http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerBatteries you will see that as far as damage to the Pi is concerned approaching 6V is the real danger.

Answer (score 3):

[The MagPi, Issue 56](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/MagPi56.pdf) got these numbers for the power usage of the B+, 2B, 3B, and Zero (note the test conditions include additional peripherals):

```
             1B+    2B     3B     Zero
Boot    Max  0.26A  0.40A  0.75A  0.20A
        Avg  0.22A  0.22A  0.35A  0.15A

Idle    Avg  0.20A  0.22A  0.30A  0.10A

Video playback (H.264) 
        Max  0.30A  0.36A  0.55A  0.23A
        Avg  0.22A  0.28A  0.33A  0.16A

Stress  Max  0.35A  0.82A  1.34A  0.35A
        Avg  0.32A  0.75A  0.85A  0.23A
```

> Test conditions used a standard Raspbian image (26 Feb 2016), at room
>   temperature, connected to an HDMI monitor, USB keyboard, and mouse.
>   For the Model 3B it was connected to a WiFi access point. All these power
>   measurements do not take into account power consumption from additional
>   USB devices; these measurements can easily be exceeded with multiple
>   additional USB devices connected or when using a HAT.

---

Some additional resources to list the power consumption of the numerous models of the Pi and different load cases:

- https://github.com/geerlingguy/raspberry-pi-dramble/wiki/Power-Consumption
- http://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi2-power-and-performance-measurement

So the reported numbers are as low as 80..100 mA for an idling A+ and 180..200 mA for the B+.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage range is mostly important for USB peripherals.  The pi itself runs at 3.3v, the 5v is only used by the USB.  USB standard is +/-5%.