# Power consumption of Pi Zero in Headless mode

Tags: pi-zero

How much power Pi Zero consumes in Headless mode?

Comment: It is an impossible question to answer without knowing what is connected to the Pi Zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Raspi.Tv](http://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi-zero-power-measurements) reports a peak draw of about 140mA, 100mA idling. You can these convert to power (watts) by multiplying by 5 (the voltage that the current is being supplied at).

[image: Chart of Pi Zero current draw figures]

While Jeff Geerling originally reported some [*extremely* low current draw figures](http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-power), it appears that he revised his measurements upwards after identifying an issue with the accuracy of his original test setup. Those [latest measurements](http://www.pidramble.com/wiki/benchmarks/power-consumption) agree with the Raspi.TV figures to within 20mA.

- HDMI off, LED off: 80 mA (0.4W)
- HDMI off, LED off, USB WiFi: 120 mA (0.7W)

Answer (score 1):

Actual measurements show they consume about 65mA (0.325 Watts at 5V) while idling and 140mA (0.7 Watts at 5V) at maximum.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40393/24224