# Portable MP3 Player

Tags: power-supply

The project is a small as possible MP3 player using the Raspberry Pi Zero. I understand the software side, but have a question about compatibility of hardware. For input/output I will be using the GPIO 40 pin with a 2.3" TFT Capacitive touch screen.

The question is in regards to powering the Raspberry Pi Zero. I noticed that Adafruit offers LiPo batteries that use the 2-pin JST connector. I want to be able to charge the device via USB while being powered from the LiPo pack. There is a handy little device also by Adafruit called the Adafruit [Micro Lipo w/MicroUSB Jack - USB LiIon/LiPoly charger](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1904).

Would I be able to use this device to power my project? From my perspective I could leave the USB exposed from the case to allow charging, use the JST connector to connect the LiPo pack, and solder the 5V/GND to an available pair of pins through a switch. Then, perhaps there is a way to program the Raspberry Pi Zero to accept power from the pins vs the micro USB connector.

Does this sound possible? Or, would the device not wake up from the pin power vs USB power? Is there another way to add rechargable batter power to the RPI Zero?

Comment: I'd like to point out that the battery it comes with is 150mah and you will definitely want a bigger one. Say 1-2 thousand mah.

Comment: [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26526/current-draw-for-2-0-models#40393) makes it seem as though that battery might power it for 1 1/2 to 2 hours.

Comment: Good call. I was planning on using their 2500 mAh battery with the project. It is the largest one they offer and still small enough to fit beside the Pi-Zero under the display.

Comment: What are you planning for audio output?