# Issue with Firefox on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-2, pi-3

When I open Firefox on Raspberry Pi 3 my Raspberry Pi devices restarts.

Is there any issue with RAM or does it not support Firefox in raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using, on which operating system?

Comment: I would once again bet on power supply. You need more power (and a good power supply) RAM issues would not restart the machine everytime you open Firefox - But high CPU usage can cause brown out every single time.

Comment: thanks @ppumkin problem is resolved,i.e power supply is less than required.

Comment: I am glad that it solved your problem. I wonder how many view this question will have in 12 months and how many people will have the same solutions :D Power supply is a nightmare with the Pi's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power supply is the main cause of Raspberry Pi restarting.

You can find some related information about power on these answers

[What's the current draw and supply voltage tolerance?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/341/whats-the-current-draw-and-supply-voltage-tolerance)

[How do I build a UPS-like - battery backup - system?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/how-do-i-build-a-ups-like-battery-backup-system)

With quite allot more information here

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply?sort=votes&pageSize=50