# Can I use a battery bank for raspberry pi?

Tags: usb-power

I am working on a project that requires a pi with a camera and a small pressure sensor board to run for up to 20 hours. I am on a budget and need a UPS for my pi model 1 B+. Any answer will be helpful.

Comment: Yes - it's straightforward. Here's a [recent answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/111599/83790) to a question along the same lines.

Comment: Yes you can use a power bank. I would recommend a pi 0 because it takes less power.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: yes, you can use a battery pack. The RPi recommends a power supply of 500mA and most good battery packs can supply more current than that. As for the 20 hours of operation, you would have to consider how many processes the RPi is running (more code being executed, more power and thus current) and the size of the battery. Just make sure your battery is rated for an output of 5v and at least 500mA with a sizable capacity. I'm using a myCharge USB-C battery pack outputting 5v at 3A max for 88.8Wh, which can run my RPi for a considerable amount of time (I haven't tested exactly the 20 hour mark).

Answer (score 2):

I have been using a 20500mh powerbank with a Pi3 B+ taking time lapse images during my working days and it has consumed only 1/4 of the powerbank charge in a 9 hour session. I believe that you can even turn off the HDMI ports if not in use and the wifi to save further power use. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just used one 8000mh to no available, works for few seconds then stops.

Comment: The power bank was not working then I bought a battery bank at Canadian Tire, 'woods' for $10, the same price as the power bank and it is working great. 4 AA batteries. I tested it for the last 24h with no problem. This battery bank did not come with its own cable.